# Call a function within flatMap, to be applied to each line of a text file

Tags: python, pandas

I am to use Spark to do some basic natural language processing. I was given a text file from which I need to do some basic transformations to output parts of speech from the file. I want to use flatMap to apply the pos_tag_counter function on each line of the text file to assign parts of speech to words in each line, but I am not able to get the lambda function to split the file by line. Instead it is splitting by word. Here is what I have so far. The first three lines remove blank lines and lines starting with 'URL':

```
import re

reg = re.compile('^(?!URL).*')
non_empty_lines = text.filter(lambda x: len(x)>0)
no_urls = non_empty_lines.filter(lambda x: reg.match(x))

phrases = no_urls.flatMap(lambda line: pos_tag_counter(line))
part_of_speech = phrases.map(lambda word: (word[1],1))

pos = part_of_speech.reduceByKey(lambda accumulator,value: accumulator + value)
```

The pos_tag_counter function within flatMap tokenizes the line and finds groups of words that form parts of speech. The flatMap call should be returning something like:

```
[('events of the day', 'NP')...]
```

with a list of tuples that fully encapsulates every part of speech in the text file. However what I'm getting when I run phrases.take(5) what I get is singular words being assigned as a part of speech:

```
[('WASHINGTON', 'NNP'),
 ('Stellar', 'NNP'),
 ('pitching', 'NN'),
 ('kept', 'VBD'),
 ('the', 'DT'),
 ('Mets', 'NNPS'),
 ('afloat', 'NN'),
 ('in', 'IN'),
 ('the', 'DT'),
 ('first', 'JJ'),
 ('half', 'NN'),
 ('of', 'IN'),
 ('last', 'JJ'),
 ('season', 'NN'),
 ('despite', 'IN')]
```

Ultimately I'll need to take the correct list and accumulate the top most common types of parts of speech and sort in descending order. Final output will look something like this:

```
[('NN', 5628),
 ('IN', 4690),
 ('NNP', 4575),
 ('DT', 3913),
 ('JJ', 2550),
 ('NNS', 2345)...
```

Comment: this looks more like Pandas code, not PySpark code?

Comment: This code is actually correct.